How to install new sink with drain on the same side as wall drain with disposal
I have a new sink I'm installing. It's a single basin with the drain on the right side. This happens to be where my wall drain is. The good thing is the wall drain is lower than the disposal drain, but it seems like a tight fit.
I've attached images to get an idea of the situation.


Is this possible? I will need to go get some new plumbing. Can I do do an immediate 90 or 45 out of the wall drain? Can I cut back the wall drain?
Thanks!

If that part of the black pipe out of the wall is an ABS or PVC pipe then it can be easily cut back some. If you do that make sure you leave enough projection to allow connection of the glue on adapter to your 1.5" drain sink piping.
It is not clear enough from your photos just what possible elbows and turns you will be able to make fit behind that disposer.

Thanks for the response! I think that's a good plan to cut back the pipe coming out of the wall. I was then thinking of doing a ABS 45 off of that. Then I can connect the  horizontal part of the p-trap to that and rotate the 45 degrees back at the trap itself so it lines up with the disposal drain elbow. I have to go get some additional parts today and then I can post a picture
